# Loop json array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I know it's been asked many times and I've gone through a good 15 - 20 questions trying to figure out how to get it to work.

JSON

```
{"menu": {
    "title":"Title One",
    "link":"Link One",
    "title":"Title Two",
    "link":"Link Two"}
}
```

PHP

```
$string = file_get_contents("test.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string,true);

foreach($json_a['menu'] as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
}
```

This so far only displays

```
title: Title Two
link: Link Two
```

as opposed to

```
title: Title One
link: Link One
title: Title Two
link: Link Two
```

Also am I correct in thinking `$json_a[menu]` does not need apostrophes because `$json_a` is not a function? it works with or without.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have multiple entries with the same key in an array. While JSON might allow it, when it's parsed by PHP, the last definition of the key,value pair wins. It looks like `menu` should be an array of objects instead.

Comment: also it will only one key out of multiple in case u do json_decode().

Comment: Object properties are unique

Comment: A little advice: If you're ever unsure of the structure of an object or array, output it with print '<pre>'; print_r($json_a); print '</pre>';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple entries with the same key in an array. While JSON might allow it, when it's parsed by PHP, the last definition of the key,value pair wins.

It looks like `menu` should be an array of objects instead:

```
{
  "menu": [{
    "title":"Title One",
    "link":"Link One"
  }, {
    "title":"Title Two",
    "link":"Link Two"
  }]
}
```

PHP

```
foreach($json_a['menu'] as $value) {
  echo $value['title'] . ": " . $value['link'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Understood, thanks Felix. Will mark as answered when timers up.